# Viewport namespace missing from SharpDX directive, please assist

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, game-engine, sharpdx

I am using Visual Studio to build my program, I have all the necessary nugets for now, installed:

```
    SharpDX
    SharpDX.D3DCompiler
    SharpDX.Direct3D11
    SharpDX.DXGI
```

Yet I get this error for Viewport:

CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Viewport' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

```
public void SetViewport(int x, int y, int width, int height)
        {
            // Set the viewport for rendering
            var viewport = new Viewport(x, y, width, height);
            d3dDeviceContext.Rasterizer.SetViewport(viewport);
        }
```

Please assist if possible, thanks.

P.S. I know I can just create a new file or a nested class but would rather know why Viewport is missing or if I am doing something incorrect.

I have tried re-installing the nuget packages, I combed each package for the namespace Viewport, I ensured all packages were up-to-date as well. I cleaned the solution and rebuilt to no avail.

Comment: Looks like [SharpDX.Mathematics](https://github.com/sharpdx/SharpDX/blob/master/Source/SharpDX.Mathematics/Viewport.cs) to me.  Odd choice.

Comment: What do you mean by odd choice? Odd choice of what directives I am using or odd to use Mathematics? I did try adding Mathematics, but did not resolve the issue. I have fought with this so long I am about to just define it myself.

Comment: Apologizes, I added, cleaned, and rebuilt now the issue is resolved. Many thanks!

Comment: @ProxyRunner - you should now answer yourself with solution you found